# Cassandra Column Family from CSV

Tags: database, csv, cassandra

Just wandering how I could go about importing a csv dataset into a Cassandra Database.

The thing is, I'm hoping that column families can be generated from the csv file. Some of my csv files have over 5000 columns. I simply need to get my datasets in the database as quick as possible.

What be the best way to go about this?

Answer (score 1):

See the documentation on [`COPY FROM`](http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/simple-data-importing-and-exporting-with-cassandra) for information on doing imports/exports fairly easily.  This will *not* create your columns automatically though, Cassandra couldn't hope to necessarily guess the data format for each column.

Comment: Ok, But then what would be the easiest and quickest method to create that data schema? It's not practical to manually define 5000 columns.

Comment: And I should add that phpmyadmin for MySQL does do this by looking at the data contained in each column.

Comment: And phpMyAdmin pretty consistently gets this wrong much of the time.  You can set a default validation class and then explicitly specify the data type for columns which are not the default.